# Router for custom module not being recognized by Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, zend-controller-router

I am following [this](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world) tutorial to create a custom module. For some reason i can't get magento to recognize the routers( i get a Magento 404 error) when i hit http://exmaple.com/helloworld/index/index.  I've verfied that the module is enabled in the Admin. There's only 2 files for this tut config.xml and IndexController.php. Thank you in advance!

Module is in /code/local/Russ/Helloworld

/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Russ_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Russ_Helloworld>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Russ_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Russ_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        echo 'Hello Index!';
    }

}

?>
```

Magento 1.6.2

Comment: did you clear your cache in the admin panel?

Comment: Did you add the file to app/etc/modules?

Comment: Yes i did.  I am able to see the custom module among the other modules in the Admin, and it is enabled

Comment: can you show the live link? Or is it hosted locally?

Comment: Break the XML in your config.xml, and turn on developer mode (see index.php). Verify a parse error.

Comment: can you run : var_dump(explode('/', trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/'))) inside your __construct(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)?

Comment: edit: no error....what i got before was trying to unbreak the config.xml file

Comment: im new to the mage core.....where exactly would i put this var dump?

Comment: im sure I have magento 1.6 somewhere on my system, give me an hour and ill take a crack at it.  { wanna see a grown man, cry? go watch him develop his first magento store :)}

Comment: v1.6 is a touchy lil git, still working on a solution for you.

Comment: I have the same problem @russjman how have you solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Magento module not being loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694661/why-is-my-magento-module-not-being-loaded)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that Store Code is not allowed to the URL:
(System > Configuration > Web > Add Store Code to Urls = No)

Thanks

Comment: well after like 2 hours of wasting my life this was my problem, still relevant 4 years on.

Comment: Does anyone know why this works? it solved my problem also but I was just wondering why,  I've searched the code base but couldn't track it down.

Answer (score 1):

Did you put a config file in app/etc/modules to activate the extension? You'll need this file to tell Magento that your extension even exists.

Try put this in app/etc/modules/Russ_Helloworld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Russ_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Russ_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then, clear Magento's cache and it should pick it up.