# Magento does not load module config.xml

Tags: magento

Magento stops load module config.xml

Cache is disabled and flushed.

The module is shows in Admin->Configuration->Advanced and module output is enabled.
Is Developer mode is enabled.

It was worked and nobody touched the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you establishing that it isn't loaded?

Comment: Check if there's any file available in /var/cache/. Sometimes magento reports that cache is flushed when it's not.

Comment: "The module is shows in Admin->Configuration->Advanced" simply means that your declaration file (should be under `app/etc/modules`) is parsed and that it contains a child node under the xpath `config/modules`, *and nothing more*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Magento module not being loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694661/why-is-my-magento-module-not-being-loaded)

Answer (score 16):

The file system path doesn't match the specifications from the module registration file.
For a registration file like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Example_TestModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Example_TestModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Magento will first take the `<codePool>` node value (watch the **upper case P** in the node name) and append that to *app/code/*, which gives us *app/code/local/*.

Next Magento takes the name of the node inside of `<modules>`, in this example `Example_TestModule`.
All underscores are converted to slashes from that string, and then it is appended to the code pool. This gives us the file system path to the module, in the example it is  *app/code/local/Example/TestModule/*.

Now the hardcoded path *etc/config.xml* is appended.

So the final path to the *config.xml* file is

```
app/code/local/Example/TestModule/etc/config.xml
```

The **casing** of the directory names **has to match** the specified path exactly.
If it doesn't it will work only on case insensitive file systems (like windows or the default OSX fs), but not on Unix.

One more thing: just like the autoloader, the first character of the namespace and module directories will be uppercased. So `<example_testModule>` would still end up being interpreted as *Example/TestModule/*.