# Magento 1.9.2.1 custom module 404

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I recently installed a clean version of Magento. I had a custom module what was working perfectly on the old one, but not on the new one(Both 1.9.2.1). It shows up under System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced. 
When ever i try to call mydomain/index.php/cron. It will redirect to the 404 page.
I tried to add the rest of the folders what are in tutorials : Block, Helper,model and sql. But no luck.
As i said it is working on the older installation with the same version number. I just copied the whole module and the file to the etc folder.

### Module structure:

- code

  - local

    - Mxsxs2

      - Cron

        - controllers

          - IndexController.php
        - etc

          - config.xml
- etc

  - modules

    - Mxsxs2_Cron.xml

### Files:

app/code/local/Mxsxs2/Cron/etc/config.xml:

```
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <config>
               <modules>
                  <Mxsxs2_Cron>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                   </Mxsxs2_Cron>
               </modules>
               <frontend>
                   <routers>
                     <cron>
                        <use>standard</use>
                         <args>
                           <module>Mxsxs2_Cron</module>
                           <frontName>cron</frontName>
                         </args>
                     </cron>
                  </routers>
               </frontend>
            </config>
```

app/code/local/Mxsxs2/Cron/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Mxsxs2_Cron_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public $importfolder="var/import"; 
    private $errormessages=array();
    private $READ=null;
    private $WRITE=null;
    private $wasindb=0;
    private $noofwarehouses=3; //for cost check   
    public function indexAction(){
       echo("asd");
    }
    //----rest of the code and fucntions they are not important if i remove them it still does not work
}
```

app/etc/modules/Mxsxs2_Cron.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mxsxs2_Cron>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mxsxs2_Cron>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento I tried the EXACT same module , which fails in Magento 1.9.2.1 but used ti run on all previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have the latest Magento 1.9.x.x installed and had a similar problem. To debug it this question helps me a lot:[Why is my Magento module not being loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694661/why-is-my-magento-module-not-being-loaded). Basically you need to check Mage_Core_Model_Config. I also wonder why I can see my module in System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced but it gives 404 error. Basically it's an error in Magento and the names for modules are broken. Somewhere Magento forces the names to have the first character Upper-case. It's not working with the first character lower-case (but it is shown in ystem->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the frontName, it may make some conflicts with newer version of magento :

```
app/code/local/Mxsxs2/Cron/etc/config.xml:

        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <config>
           <modules>
              <Mxsxs2_Cron>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
               </Mxsxs2_Cron>
           </modules>
           <frontend>
               <routers>
                 <cron>
                    <use>standard</use>
                     <args>
                       <module>Mxsxs2_Cron</module>
                       <frontName>testname</frontName>
                     </args>
                 </cron>
              </routers>
           </frontend>
        </config>
```

clear cache then access the url mydomain/index.php/testname